# Sum two values from 2 span elements (the values for each span element can be selected by the user via dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made two forms. The user is able to select a value (product) from each form whose price is then displayed in a separate  element with unique class. when one option from the form is selected the others are hidden. I did that. Now, I can't seem to sum those values from the  elements into the . Here is what I've done for the html:

```
<div id="netpaketi-wrapper"> 
<strong><p class="textmain"><b>Изберете го Вашиот хостинг пакет</b>
</p></strong>
    <form class="hosting-biranje" action="">
        <select name="hosting">
        <option value="licen" class="ls" selected="selected">ЛИЧЕН СЕРВЕР</option>
        <option value="biznisl" class="bl">БИЗНИС L</option>
        <option value="xl" class="bxl">БИЗНИС XL</option>
        <option value="xxl" class="bxxl">БИЗНИС XXL</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <div id="opis-paket">
        <div class="hosting-paket-opis licen-s">
            <p class="opisno">Windows/Linux</p>
            <p class="opisno">РАМ до 1GB</p>
            <p class="opisno">Процесор: Intel-core-I-7-4770</p>
            <p class="opisno">Bandwith 570 Mbits/s</p>
            <p class="opisno">Безбедност на податоците (SSL)</p>
            <p class="opisno">Бeсплатен домен</p>
            <p class="opisno">FTP пристап</p>
        </div>

        <div class="hosting-paket-opis server-l">
            <p class="opisno">Windows/Linux</p>
            <p class="opisno">РАМ до 2GB</p>
            <p class="opisno">Процесор: Intel-core-I-7-4770</p>
            <p class="opisno">Bandwith 570 Mbits/s</p>
            <p class="opisno">Безбедност на податоците (SSL)</p>
            <p class="opisno">Бeсплатен домен</p>
            <p class="opisno">FTP пристап</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hosting-paket-opis server-xl">
            <p class="opisno">Windows/Linux</p>
            <p class="opisno">РАМ до 4GB</p>
            <p class="opisno">Процесор: Intel-core-I-7-4770</p>
            <p class="opisno">Bandwith 570 Mbits/s</p>
            <p class="opisno">Безбедност на податоците (SSL)</p>
            <p class="opisno">Бeсплатен домен</p>
            <p class="opisno">FTP пристап</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hosting-paket-opis server-xxl">
            <p class="opisno">Windows/Linux</p>
            <p class="opisno">РАМ до 8GB</p>
            <p class="opisno">Процесор: Intel-core-I-7-4770</p>
            <p class="opisno">Bandwith 570 Mbits/s</p>
            <p class="opisno">Безбедност на податоците (SSL)</p>
            <p class="opisno">Бeсплатен домен</p>
            <p class="opisno">FTP пристап</p>
        </div>

        <p class="opisno">Цена: <span class="cena-hosting">1200</span> денари годишно</p>
    </div>
```

This is the html for the first form. The html for the second form is:

```
<div id="netpaketi-wrapper"> 
<strong><p class="textmain"><b>Изберете го Вашиот вебсајт пакет</b>
</p></strong>
    <form class="vebsajt-biranje" action="">
        <select name="vebpaket">
        <option value="osnoven" class="vpo" selected="selected">ОСНОВЕН</option>
        <option value="e-mono" class="vpem">Е-МОНО</option>
        <option value="e-duo" class="vped">Е-ДУО</option>
        <option value="e-divers" class="vpedi">Е-ДИВЕРС</option>
        <option value="osnoven-market" class="vpmo">МАРКЕТ ОСНОВЕН</option>
        <option value="mono-market" class="vpmm">МАРКЕТ МОНО</option>
        <option value="duo-market" class="vpmd">МАРКЕТ ДУО</option>
        <option value="diverce-market" class="vpmdi">МАРКЕТ ДИВЕРС</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <div id="opis-paket">
        <div class="vebsajt-paket-opis osnoven-paket">
            <p class="opisno">Сајт дизајниран од нас според Вашите потреби</p>
        </div>

        <div class="vebsajt-paket-opis e-mono-paket">
            <p class="opisno">Сајт дизајниран според Вашите желби и потреби чии страни ќе имаат сличен изглед и функции</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vebsajt-paket-opis e-duo-paket">
            <p class="opisno">Сајт дизајниран според Вашите желби и потреби чија почетна страна ќе се разликува од останатите страни во поглед на функции изглед</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vebsajt-paket-opis e-divers-paket">
            <p class="opisno">Сајт дизајниран според Вашите желби и потреби чии страни значително ќе се разликуваат  во поглед на функции и изглед</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vebsajt-paket-opis market-osnoven-paket">
            <p class="opisno">Сајт дизајниран од нас според Вашите потреби. Интегрирано е-плаќање</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vebsajt-paket-opis market-mono-paket">
            <p class="opisno">Сајт дизајниран според Вашите желби и потреби чии страни ќе имаат сличен изглед и функции. Интегрирано е-плаќање</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vebsajt-paket-opis market-duo-paket">
            <p class="opisno">Сајт дизајниран според Вашите желби и потреби чија почетна страна ќе се разликува од останатите страни во поглед на функции изглед. Интегрирано е-плаќање</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vebsajt-paket-opis market-divers-paket">
            <p class="opisno">Сајт дизајниран според Вашите желби и потреби чии страни значително ќе се разликуваат  во поглед на функции и изглед. Интегрирано е-плаќање</p>
        </div>

        <p class="opisno">Цена: <span class="cena-vebsajt">6000</span> денари</p>
    </div>
```

The element where the sum should be displayed is:

```
<a href="#" class="g-btn type_primary"><span class="iznos"></span> денари</a>
```

That's the html, and this is the jQuery code used for hiding/showing the selected values:

```
<script>
    var jq=$.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function(){

        jq(".ls").click(function(){
     jq(".licen-s").show();
     jq(".server-l, .server-xl, .server-xxl").hide();
     jQuery.removeData(".cena-hosting");
     jq(".cena-hosting").text("1200");
         });

         jq(".bl").click(function(){
     jq(".server-l").show();
     jq(".licen-s, .server-xl, .server-xxl").hide();
     jQuery.removeData(".cena-hosting");
     jq(".cena-hosting").text("2200");
         });

         jq(".bxl").click(function(){
     jq(".server-xl").show();
     jq(".server-l, .licen-s, .server-xxl").hide();
     jQuery.removeData(".cena-hosting");
     jq(".cena-hosting").text("2600");
         });

         jq(".bxxl").click(function(){
     jq(".server-xxl").show();
     jq(".server-l, .server-xl, .licen-s").hide();
     jQuery.removeData(".cena-hosting");
     jq(".cena-hosting").text("2900");
         });





         jq(".vpo").click(function(){
     jq(".osnoven-paket").show();
     jq(".e-mono-paket, .e-duo-paket, .e-divers-paket, .market-osnoven-paket, .market-mono-paket, .market-duo-paket, .market-divers-paket").hide();
            jQuery.removeData(".cena-vebsajt");
        jq(".cena-vebsajt").text("6000");    
         });

         jq(".vpem").click(function(){
     jq(".e-mono-paket").show();
     jq(".osnoven-paket, .e-duo-paket, .e-divers-paket, .market-osnoven-paket, .market-mono-paket, .market-duo-paket, .market-divers-paket").hide();
            jQuery.removeData(".cena-vebsajt");
        jq(".cena-vebsajt").text("36000");
         });

         jq(".vped").click(function(){
     jq(".e-duo-paket").show();
     jq(".e-mono-paket, .osnoven-paket, .e-divers-paket, .market-osnoven-paket, .market-mono-paket, .market-duo-paket, .market-divers-paket").hide();
            jQuery.removeData(".cena-vebsajt");
        jq(".cena-vebsajt").text("56000");
         });

         jq(".vpedi").click(function(){
     jq(".e-divers-paket").show();
     jq(".e-mono-paket, .e-duo-paket, .osnoven-paket, .market-osnoven-paket, .market-mono-paket, .market-duo-paket, .market-divers-paket").hide();
            jQuery.removeData(".cena-vebsajt");
        jq(".cena-vebsajt").text("66000");
         });             

         jq(".vpmo").click(function(){
     jq(".market-osnoven-paket").show();
     jq(".e-mono-paket, .e-duo-paket, .e-divers-paket, .osnoven-paket, .osnoven-paket, .market-mono-paket, .market-duo-paket, .market-divers-paket").hide();
            jQuery.removeData(".cena-vebsajt");
        jq(".cena-vebsajt").text("26000");
         });

         jq(".vpmm").click(function(){
     jq(".market-mono-paket").show();
     jq(".e-mono-paket, .e-duo-paket, .e-divers-paket, .market-osnoven-paket, .osnoven-paket, .market-duo-paket, .market-divers-paket").hide();
            jQuery.removeData(".cena-vebsajt");
        jq(".cena-vebsajt").text("56000");       
         });

         jq(".vpmd").click(function(){
     jq(".market-duo-paket").show();
     jq(".e-mono-paket, .e-duo-paket, .e-divers-paket, .market-osnoven-paket, .market-mono-paket, .osnoven-paket, .market-divers-paket").hide();
            jQuery.removeData(".cena-vebsajt");
        jq(".cena-vebsajt").text("86000");
         });

         jq(".vpmdi").click(function(){
     jq(".market-divers-paket").show();
     jq(".e-mono-paket, .e-duo-paket, .e-divers-paket, .market-osnoven-paket, .market-mono-paket, .market-duo-paket, .osnoven-paket").hide();
            jQuery.removeData(".cena-vebsajt");
        jq(".cena-vebsajt").text("160000");
         });
        });
</script>
```

The first four block of codes is for the first form, and the last 8 blocks are for the second form.
For the sum I've tried this code:

```
<script>
var jq=$.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    var newprice = Number(text(".cena-vebsajt")) + Number(text(".cena-hosting"));
    jq('.iznos').append(newprice);
});
</script>
```

But I can't get a result, it doesn't show anything for the value
I have also tried with:

```
<script>
var jq=$.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    var newprice = Number(.cena-vebsajt) + Number(".cena-hosting");
    jq('.iznos').append(newprice);
});
</script>
```

But, again, no result.
Here is the link to the page: http://netarchitecture.de/mk/netpaketi.asp
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/e3e4vhkj/

The trick is to use parseFloat or parseInt depending on the numbers you have.

```
var one=parseFloat($('.cena-vebsajt').text());
var two=parseFloat($('.cena-hosting').text());
var res=one+two;
$('.result').text(res);
```

Be careful however when you are not sure whether the text of the span could be non-numeric. Use $.isNumeric for instance.